# How to post string and video to PHP server?

Tags: php, ios, post, upload, nsurlconnection

I have the following problem.. I am trying to post video data and some strings to a PHP server. I am able to post the video data, but I don't know how to add strings. Here's the code I am using, it works excellent for posting video, but now I have to add text to the post.

```
- (NSData *)generatePostDataForData:(NSData *)uploadData
{
    // Generate the post header:
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithCString:"--AaB03x\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_mp4\"; filename=\"movie.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    // Get the post header int ASCII format:
    NSData *postHeaderData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    // Generate the mutable data variable:
    NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:[postHeaderData length]];
    [postData setData:postHeaderData];

    // Add the video:
    [postData appendData: uploadData];

    // Add the closing boundry:
    [postData appendData: [@"\r\n--AaB03x--" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

    // Return the post data:
    return postData;
}

-(void)post:(NSData *)fileData
{
    NSLog(@"POSTING");

    // Generate the postdata:
    NSData *postData = [self generatePostDataForData: fileData];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    // Setup the request:
    NSMutableURLRequest *uploadRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pik.bg/android_test.php"] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval: 30];
    [uploadRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [uploadRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [uploadRequest setValue:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [uploadRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    // Execute the reqest:
    //NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:uploadRequest delegate:self];
     NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:uploadRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog (@"%@", returnString);
}

    // Button for sending the news to the web.
-(IBAction)sendNews:(id)sender
{
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoString];
    [self post:videoData];
}
```

Now I want to add some text to "title" and "description" text boxes. How to do that with this kind of code?

Answer (score 1):

Use This may be helpfull ..

```
NSString *strURL =@"Your URL";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
//Image Uploading
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_mp4\"; filename=\"movie.mp4\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *videoData = @"Your video in data Format";
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


//Data Sending
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Your Key That's need on server\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Your Data That's you want to send on server" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data Return From Server %@",returnString);
```

I have changed my answer. Now check and arrange according your server need.

Comment: what did you add your key and value in post data that available on server . Actually I use this code for upload image with content on server. then everthing is working

Comment: @scourGINHO .. See again I have changed my answer

Comment: Actually When I select the video from gallary than it will take .mov file and than how we can send it as mp4.

Comment: but when i got that video url from server it is not playing my simulator or device but it is playing on P.C browser.@Jogendra.Com

Comment: try AVPlayer In this playing mp4 files